# How to read a list into an Extended SelectListItem class with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am developing in VS 2015 using C#, MVC and EF6. I currently generate select list content using the following:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> slist = new SelectList(dbContext.UserCategories
            .Where(x => x.DisplayOrder > 0)
            .OrderBy(x => x.UserCategoryType)
            .ThenBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)
            .ToList(), "UserCategoryID", "Category");
```

I need to extend the `SelectListItem` class as follows:

```
public class ExtendedSelectListItem : SelectListItem
{
    public string HtmlAttribute { get; set; }

    public ExtendedSelectListItem()
    {
    }        
}
```

My questions is, how do I modify the EF expression to generate a suitable result for the new class. (Please note that field `UserCategoryID` is an `int`)

Comment: Extend it to do what?

Comment: Bad title; updated to clarify hopefully

Comment: Are you writing your own html helper extension methods to render an `<select>` with additional attributes in each of its options?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to add an HTML class to each item in the list which will be different depending on the item type.

Comment: Eriks answer would be easier, but you could also write your own `SelectList` method that accepts an additional parameter(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any requirement to make a `SelectList` so you could:

```
vars list = dbContext.UserCategories
  .Where(x => x.DisplayOrder > 0)
  .OrderBy(x => x.UserCategoryType)
  .ThenBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)
  .ToList()
  .Select(uc => new ExtendedSelectListItem()
    {
      HtmlAttribute = "form-control",
      Value = uc.UserCategoryID.ToString(),
      Text = uc.UserCategoryType
    })
  .ToList()
```

Something like that works for `Html.DropDownListFor()` etc.  (Not however, that `HtmlAttribute` is unknown to `DropDownListFor` and other built in methods, so it won't render anything unless you wrote your own methods that know how to consume `ExtendedSelectListItem`).

Comment: Thanks for this, see comment above for answer to consuming the object